# How do you get the graphics to display to a jframe?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I can't seem to get the my render class to draw onto the Jframe (or JComponent). 
JFrame appears but is not green and doesn't output "green" to console.

Probably missing something quite crucial

```
public class Game_1 {

    public static JFrame frame;
    public static Render render;
    public static Game_1 game;

    public Game_1() {
        frame = new JFrame("Game 1");
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(render = new Render());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        game = new Game_1();
        render.repaint();
    }
}


public class Render extends JComponent {
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

        System.out.println("Green");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Render` should override `paintComponent` of `JComponent` , so rename your `render` method to `paintComponent` .

Comment: @Berger Your a star! Many Thanks